# How do I disbale lock after pm-hibernate thaw?

Tags: 22.04, encryption, hibernate, pm-utils

I use full disk encryption, so when coming out of hibernation, I only want to enter one password (encryption passphrase) not a second (account password).

When I use the standard systemd-hibernate, this works. Only one password is needed. Which is what I want. But with pm-hibernate, it locks so I have to put in two passwords (encryption passphrase + account password). Which is not what I want. It's cumbersome.

Right now, I'm using pm-hibernate to try to diagnose a problem, but I'm annoyed by having to put in two passwords every time. I've looked into the configurations of pm-hibernate, s2disk, and uswsusp, but can't find any configuration parameter that would let me skip locking.

My setup:

- Dell Inspiron 15 (3535)
- Ubuntu 22.04
- LUKS encrypted LVM2 PV
- 16 GB of ram
- 21 GB swap LVM
- Automatic Screen Lock disabled
- Lock Screen on Suspend disabled
- Automatic Login enabled

Thanks in advance.